# Text Display for Tiny Lisp Computer 2

Tags: arduino

**Question about Porting Specific Bit-Banging Code from Arduino UNO to mega2560**

This is a question to David Johnson Davies, posted here as his blog uses Disqus, making it hard to post code samples.

The blog article is here [Text Display for the Arduino UNO](http://www.technoblogy.com/show?1H44)

**Working Code**

Having a hard time understanding how the following code works, specifically the `PIND` assignments, and how the same code brings the wire low / high, unless you're just relying on the earlier assignment to a different pin...

```cpp
// Write a data byte to the display
void Data (uint8_t d) {  
  PIND = 1<<cs; // cs low
  for (uint8_t bit = 0x80; bit; bit >>= 1) {
    PIND = 1<<clk; // clk low
    if (d & bit) PORTB = PORTB | (1<<data); else PORTB = PORTB & ~(1<<data);
    PIND = 1<<clk; // clk high
  }
  PIND = 1<<cs; // cs high
}

// Write a command byte to the display
void Command (uint8_t c) { 
  PIND = 1<<dc; // dc low
  Data(c);
  PIND = 1<<dc; // dc high
}
```

That is your original code, which works on my Diecimila! So I'm not doubting the code.

**Ported Non-Working Code**

However moving it to pins 6,7,8,10 on the mega 2560 is *not* working, despite structuring the ports with the data pin on bit 4 of `PORTB`, and the other 3 lines on `PORTH`, similarly to you using `PORTD` for `cs,dc,clk`, but with data on bit 0 of `PORTB`. Anything obvious wrong with the below?

```cpp
// move pins to 6,7,8,10
// pin 6 PH3 
int const cs = 3;         // Bit in PORTH
int const cspin = 6;
// pin 7 PH4 
int const dc = 4;         // Bit in PORTH
int const dcpin = 7;
// pin 8 PH5
int const clk = 5;        // Bit in PORTH
int const clkpin = 8;
// pin 10 PB4
int const data = 4;       // Bit in PORTB
int const datapin = 10;

// Write a data byte to the display
void Data (uint8_t d) {  
  PINH = 1<<cs; // cs low
  for (uint8_t bit = 0x80; bit; bit >>= 1) {
    PINH = 1<<clk; // clk low
    if (d & bit) PORTB = PORTB | (1<<data); else PORTB = PORTB & ~(1<<data);
    PINH = 1<<clk; // clk high
  }
  PINH = 1<<cs; // cs high
}

// Write a command byte to the display
void Command (uint8_t c) { 
  PINH = 1<<dc; // dc low
  Data(c);
  PINH = 1<<dc; // dc high
}

void InitDisplay () {
  // Define pins
  pinMode(dcpin, OUTPUT); digitalWrite(dcpin,HIGH);
  pinMode(clkpin, OUTPUT); digitalWrite(clkpin,HIGH);
  pinMode(datapin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(cspin, OUTPUT); digitalWrite(cspin,HIGH);
  for (uint8_t c=0; c<InitLen; c++) Command(Init[c]);
  Display(12);    // Clear display
  Command(0xAF);  // Display on
}
```

Thanks for any advice! And thanks for all this wonderful work you have done.